# Catching dangling or unused Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, future, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, futuretask

A common problem in our Scala code is that a call that returns a `Future[T]` will not be awaited (we commonly use the [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/scala-async) library because many of us are familiar with async/await from C#) or used at all; it is simply discarded. Is there any way to get a warning or is there a 3rd-party code analysis tool that will catch this?

Obviously this applies primarily to "side effecting" Futures, such as storing an object in a database. I realize this could be solved by using a more purely-functional approach such as the IO Monad, but let's assume we're dead set on using the built-in Future for the sake of argument.

This becomes harmful when (for instance), it is critical that an operation complete successfully before proceeding. A common example for us would be receiving a message from a message broker, storing it to a database, then only when that operation is complete do we commit the receipt of the message to the broker. Often it's just too easy to carelessly say:

```
storeObject()
commitToBroker()

// instead of...
await(storeObject())
await(commitToBroker())

// or...
storeObject().flatMap(_ => commitToBroker())
```

We've taken to call this issue a "dangling Future" and we have the policy that at the very least any Future should include an `andThen()` that logs any error. However we have no automated way to catch violations of this policy, and I am not aware of a warning flag that would work.

Comment: Have you tried the scalac switch "-Ywarn-value-discard" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a compiler plugin that will do this, but I have a few recommendations:

First, use the scalac flag `-Ywarn-unused` in conjunction with `-Xfatal-warnings`. This way anytime you return a Future, or any other value, that isn't consumed you'll get an error.

Second, avoid creating Futures with the built-in methods and instead create your own constructor/factory that creates Futures with a default logging policy.

Three, to enforce the second point, create scalastyle rules that check for and prohibit `Future {...}`, `Future.successful`, or `Future.failure`.